# expect , need to treat expression and print results on screen

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

Guys i have the following problem , i'm issuing the command free in a busybox host , i wanna check how much memory i have free, i need to print if the result is bigger than 10M then i should return something like " i have more than 30M free" etc... i dont know how to treat the output from expect.
i have the code snippet

```
expect "$"
send "df -h\r"
expect "$"
send "uptime\r"
expect "$"
send "free | awk -F ' ' ' FNR == 2 {print \$3}'\r"
expect "$"
```

how to treat the output from the command free ? that output would give me integer with the free memory i need to analyze a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might want check if the Busybox version of `free` is the same as GNU, but on my Fedora system, `free`'s output looks like

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3094900    2691252     403648          0     442924     983336
-/+ buffers/cache:    1264992    1829908
Swap:      2064380     126268    1938112
```

To get free memory, this would do it:

```
free | awk -F ' ' ' FNR == 2 {print \$4}'
```

To capture `Expect` output in a tcl variable:

```
set results $expect_out(buffer)
```

So the way to do what you want is approximately

```
send "free | awk -F ' ' ' FNR == 2 {print \$4}'\r"
set freeram $expect_out(buffer)
if { $freeram >= 10000 }  {
    puts "You have lots of free memory.\n"
}
```

Comment: i tried that but looks like the variable comes empty

Comment: @user3847270:  Did you check the output format from your version of the `free` command?  Busybox has numerous small differences of this kind.

Comment: yes , its the same output as your fedora actually...the command returns okay with the free memory but the buffer is empty for some reason , i tried to puts $freeram nothings comes.

Comment: @user3847270:  try the inner command at a command prompt and see if that much works:  `free | awk -F ' ' ' FNR == 2 {print $4}'`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a Linux variant (remotely), the easiest way to get the amount of free memory over ssh is to not use `free`. Instead, you can use a different approach entirely:

```
spawn ssh $user@$theOtherHost cat /proc/meminfo
expect {
    -re {MemTotal:\s+(\d+) kB} {
        set total $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    -re {MemFree:\s+(\d+) kB} {
        set free $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
    "Password:" {
        send "$thePassword\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        # Do nothing; default fall-through is fine
    }
}

puts "usage was $free out of $total (both in kilobytes)"
```